# Are hashmaps typically implemented with an array of keys?

Tags: python, c++, rust, hashmap, iterator

Many languages that include hashmaps in the standard library or as builtins, allow the programmer to iterate over the hashmap. For example, in python:

```
d = {"US": "English", "Spain": "Spanish", "France": "French", "Canada": "English"}
for key in d:
    print(key)
```

Or C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main(){
        unordered_map <string, string> m;

        m["US"] = "English";
        m["Spain"] = "Spanish";
        m["France"] = "French";
        m["Canada"] = "English";

        for (auto &it: m){
                cout << it.first << endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Rust also has a similar thing and the iteration looks more like the python.

So my question is: Do the hashmap implementations contain a vector of keys that they can iterate over, and either just give you the key or lookup the value on the fly in O(1)? Or do they go through the actual hash table including empty buckets?

I ask because in the latter case, presumably it's more efficient to keep a list of keys myself and iterate that way, rather than actually use the map's functionality.

Edit: Perhaps I was unclear in this question. The purpose of a hashmap is to associate keys with values in O(1) time. All of these implementations do that well. But when you want to iterate over all the key/value pairs in your map, there are two different ways I can think of to achieve that. One is to have an array of your keys, go through that array, lookup each key in O(1) time, and print the key/value. This takes O(n) because you have *n* keys.

The other way is to run a for loop over the hashmap and extract the keys, values, or both. My question is whether this form typically comes with a speed penalty because the hashtable has empty buckets that need to be checked as we iterate. Normally it seems obvious that we should incur this penalty, but I feel like if I were implementing a library like this I would keep an array of keys and when the user requests to iterate I would do it the first way.

Comment: if you have to iterate, you don't have O(1).  You hash the key and that gives you the bucket to go to.  then you have to find the element in that bucket.  It should be noted that the way `unordered_map` is specified it is basically a `std::vector<std::list<>>` which doesn't have the best performance compared to other hash maps.

Comment: _it's more efficient to keep a list of keys myself and iterate that way, rather than actually use the map's functionality._ Is there any reason for you to use hashmaps then?

Comment: Do you understand the meaning and purpose of `hash`?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Hash maps keep pairs (key, value). It's unclear why you want to keep keys separately.

Comment: You can always just use a `Vec<(Key, Value)>`, but I suspect you're prematurely optimizing; and that hashmap will be faster in most scenarios (unless the default safe hasher is too slow, but you can fix that by swapping hashers). Run some benchmarks and see which data structure is the most performant for your work.

Comment: what would you do with the vector when inserting or removing elements from the hash map? If you never insert or remove elements, and just want a container with random access then yes a vector is more efficient, but then you dont need the hashmap in the first place

Comment: AFAIK python does have both a list of keys, and a hash map in its dictionary, there is no "typically", each library is free to implement it as it sees fit.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Python does not have "both a list of keys and a hashmap". It has a dense array of (hash, key, value), and it has a sparse array of indices into the latter. The composition of both is the hashmap.

Comment: and then you have C# ReadOnlyDictionary being an AVL-Tree.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason. not to.

Comment: Iterating over maps is certainly less efficient than iterating over arrays. But if done *occasionally*, i.e. the ratio between map iteration and individual element *lookup by key* is low, then it can still be more efficient to iterate than to maintain an entirely separate array just for the purpose of occasional iteration.

Comment: C++  `std` defines 3 similar yet different data structures: `std::map` is implemented as a red-black tree; `std::unordered_map` uses **hash data structure**; `std::flat_map` keeps keys and values in separate containers of user's choice(defaulting to vector). The last one os still under review and development. Former 2 have **set** counterparts; you can consider them  sets of key-value pairs with minimal interface enhancements.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is: Do the hashmap implementations contain a vector of keys that they can iterate over, and either just give you the key or lookup the value on the fly in O(1)? Or do they go through the actual hash table including empty buckets?

> I ask because in the latter case, presumably it's more efficient to keep a list of keys myself and iterate that way, rather than actually use the map's functionality.

It would be more efficient for this specific iteration but it would be a lot less efficient for storage, and might also be less efficient when iterating the values or entries: now you'd have to hash and look up the entry (which has to store the key again) on each item.

So no, when iterating the hashmap will iterate the array of entries, and skip over the empty ones.

It's also possible to have a dense array of entries, that's the case of Python (since 3.6) or `indexmap` in Rust, the former specifically switched to that layout to improve iteration performance.

Comment: *"specifically switched to that layout to improve iteration performance"* - Actually it [looks like](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-December/123028.html) saving space was the main reason.